# How to select specific portion of url in xmlNodeList

Tags: c#, asp.net, innertext, xmlnodelist

In my project, I have a `.pdf` to generate, for that, I am getting `full path` of .pdf file. Now there is need where I have to select only name of pdf file, say `file1.pdf` from `url`. How to perform this?

My code for the same :

```
 string url = string.Empty;
                    string Result = objAjaxService.generateStatementpdf(hdnActiveUserNumber.Value.ToString(), "", "", rdpFromEmail.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), rdpToEmail.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
                    Result = Result.Replace("\n", " ");
                    Result = Result.Replace("&", " ");
                    Result = RemoveWhitespaceWithSplit(Result);
                    if (Result.Contains("url"))
                    {
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(Result);
                        XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/url");
                        if (xnList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            url = xnList.Item(0).InnerText;

                        }
```

Here, I am getting `url` : `http://localhost:63303/pdfreports/427statement.pdf`.

I want to store `427statement.pdf` in a string say, `serverpath`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
[^\/]+.pdf$
```

usage:

```
string res = Regex.Match(myUrl, "[^\\/]+.pdf$").Value;
```